# When streaming / recording my desktop, how do I also record the audio?

Tags: streaming, avconv, video-streaming

I'm running the latest Ubuntu on my PC and want to **stream my whole desktop** to a TV screen connected to a *Raspberry Pi* running XBMC.

So far I manage to grab the stream wit `avconf`.

Dumping it in a file works and so does streaming it to the XBMC over HTTP (I created [`.strm` files](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Internet_video_and_audio_streams) on a source in the XBMC to have easy access to the streams). The stream takes a couple of seconds to load and after that I have a delay of about 4 seconds between actions on my screen and the result on the TV.

That's okay for me but can probably be tweaked with better codec or transport settings (RTS maybe?).

**My problem is though: I can't record any audio.**

Neither when dumping to a file nor when streaming to the XBMC. 
So I guess the problem has to do something with the grabbing command or my audio setup?

I use the following command to grab my screen:

```
avconv \
  -f x11grab -s 1920x1080 -r 25 -i :0.0+0.0 \
  -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse \
  -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -s 1280x720 \
  -acodec libmp3lame \
  -threads 0 test.avi
```

And the next one to stream it:

```
avconv ... -f mpegts - | \
  vlc -I dummy - --sout='#std{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:$PORT}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The above command was okay.**

At default it only records from the microphone entry slot. Since I had no microphone connected, no sound was recorded. But I want to record the "internal" sound anyway and not a microphone voiceover or something.

So I needed to install **pavucontrol** - like `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol` - to switch my recording source. Started it, gone to the *Recording* tab and changed audio capture to *Monitor of Internal Audio Analog Stereo*.

Seems that the setting is remembered. Every time I record a stream now, I record my internal sound.